# Issue regarding to set a checkbox with a particular value among all checkboxes with same id and class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an existing web application. Now I am facing a particular problem regarding some javascript. I have a list of checkbox with same classname, id and name. That means all checkbox will have the same class,name and id. Only the value will be different for each checkbox.

The code is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Austin Engineering" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="FAG" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Jeekay" /></td>

</tr>
```

Now the problem is that through javascript after checking some condition I have to set the checkbox with a specific value.

I have tried the following line of code,but it is not working.

```
$("#brand_id_").attr("value",'FAG').attr("checked", true);
```

It was setting the first checkbox. And that checkbox has a different value.

Please help me to find out a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: using same `id`s are invalid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class selector, and check for value attribute.

```js
$(".brand_tag[value='FAG']").attr("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Austin Engineering" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="FAG" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Jeekay" /></td>

</tr>
```

Although this will work but please note that element with duplicate Ids means your HTML is invalid. Try to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$(".brand_tag[value=FAG]").attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set your check boxes with different ID's, and then you can use either class selector or ID selector or tag selector.

If you want to set the value and the checked property of all the checkboxes to 'FAG' and true respectively, use the following:

```
$(".brand_tag").attr("value",'FAG').attr("checked", true);
```

If you want to set the properties for a specific checkbox, use the ID selector after you change the ID's of your checkboxes as follows:

```
$("#NewID1").attr("value",'FAG').attr("checked", true);
```

where `NewID1` is the ID of that specific checkbox that you want to modify its properties.

Comment: setting unique id is not necessary I think. I have implemented the suggestion provided by @anu and it is working fine.

Comment: Ya that's right anu solution is perfect. However, you can also change the ID's and select the ID of the specific checkbox and set its attributes instead of checking for value attribute. This will look like this $("#NewID1").attr("checked", true); where the NewID1 is the ID of the checkbox with the property value = 'FAG'

Comment: "The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS)."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id
Good luck with your approach, be ready for surprise

Comment: Sorry, my purpose was not that. I coded all checkbox with same id intentionally. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value='FAG']").prop("checked", true);
```

As your code attr("value",'FAG') will change the value of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Check my examples :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/6cz22b18/4/

```
<table id="brand_id_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtInput" value="FAG"></td>
    <td><button onclick="$.setCheckbox()">Check</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Austin Engineering" />Austin Engineering</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="FAG" />FAG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="Jeekay" />Jeekay</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="FAG" />FAG</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$.setCheckbox = function() {
    // reset
    $("#brand_id_table").find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);

  // set checkbox
  $("#brand_id_table").find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == $("#txtInput").val()) {
      $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
  });
}
```

1. '$("#brand_id_table").find("input:checkbox")' is items
2. so, you have to use each() function that is like a 'for statement'.